# Export данных в Excel

Tags: php

```
<?php
// Connection 
$conn=mysql_connect('localhost','realdrny_6','RHJJh&');
$db=mysql_select_db('realdrny_6',$conn);
$filename = "Webinfopen.xls"; // File Name
// Download file
header('Content-type: application/x-msdownload; charset=utf-16');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=companies.xls');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');
echo pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf); 
$user_query = mysql_query('select name,surname from Clients');
// Write data to file
$flag = false;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query)) {
    if (!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t \t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Из за echo pack("CCC",0xef,0xbb,0xbf); ломается табуляция и все в одну строку лепится

Comment: ну не делай echo pack ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Вообще обычно разработчики вначале формируют цельные данные для output (складируют всё в одну переменную) и только единожды пишут echo output.

Comment: Под ваши нужды уже имеется готовая библиотека: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet